# Check value of multidimensional dict (array_column)

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have the necessity to check if a specific value correspond to the value of a multidimensional dict (specifying the key).

```
multi_dict = [
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'},
{'key1': 'value10', 'key2': 'value20', 'key3': 'value30'}
]
```

I'm coming from a PHP environment and I know that there's a function that does that: [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) There's something like this also for Python?

Possible output specifying key1 in order to check if a value correspond:

```
[value1, value10]
```

Comment: Can you give your expected output?

Comment: so you need all `key1` values  across all dicts?

Comment: I added a possible output, but mainly I need to check if a static value correspond to the values of a multi dict specifying the key, so if I can return all the values of a specific key in a simple list I can do it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
multi_dict = [
    {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'},
    {'key1': 'value10', 'key2': 'value20', 'key3': 'value30'}
]

result = [d['key1'] for d in multi_dict]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['value1', 'value10']
```

---

If you wanted to emulate the third argument of `array_column`, the index key, you can use dictionary comprehension:

```
result = {d['key1']: d['key2'] for d in multi_dict}
print(result)
```

Output:

```
{'value1': 'value2', 'value10': 'value20'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all values for a key of all dicts:

```
multi_dict = [ {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'},
               {'key1': 'value10', 'key2': 'value20', 'key3': 'value30'},
               {                   'key2': 'value30', 'key3': 'value40'},
             ]

val_key1 = [d.get('key1') for d in multi_dict] 

print(val_key1)
```

Output:

```
['value1', 'value10', None]
```

You should use `dict.get(key)` to get a `None` in case a key is missing.

Doku:

- [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey) (StackOverflow)
- [dict.get(key)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) (python.org)